# Get hd720 / hd1080 stream for Youtube video

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube

I want to play a YouTube video in my iPhone app **without** embedding it inside an UIWebView.

I found an Objective C utility that extracts the "medium" and "small" streams from a given YouTube URL. https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView . But instead I want the 1080p and/or 720p streams!

The goal is to be able to play that stream using `AVPlayer` or `MPVideoViewController`.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: It appears that the LBYouTubeView project simply tries to extract the URL/s from youtube (violating their EULA). While doing so, it locates the M3U8 streams (if available) offered for iOS devices. Those streams seem to be non HD and hence that project fails - well, it fails on a number of other issues as noted in their bug-section. If I was you, I would not try to rely on that project or any other project tricking YouTube by circumventing their player. Whenever YT decides to change the way they deliver their content (dHTML), your app will break.

Comment: I am aware of that. But I know there is a way to do so! Because there are other iPhone/iPad apps that also play Youtube videos... Example: "Jasmine".

I know my app has to be free when I find a way to do it, but that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this can get you started, it is a JavaScript bookmarklet to capture *all* YouTube streams.

[`svnpenn.github.io/bm`](http://svnpenn.github.com/bm)

Comment: Yes this is it! I ported that JavaScript code to Objective C and it successfully builds 720p and 1080p URL's for me! Thank you very much!!